проблема с git log
Изучал основы гита с помощью githowto, и столкнулся с проблемой. Попытался изменить вывод логов с помощью git config --global, в итоге что-то сделал не так, и при каждом запуске git log появляется ошибка:
fatal: invalid --pretty format: --oneline
Помогите пожалуйста исправить, нигде не нашел информацию об этом.

Так а что устанавливал через config --global?

oneline только, я похоже неправильно установил, и не знаю как откатить изменения

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Откройте файл конфигурации гита в текстовом редакторе и удалите добавленную строку

Я зашел в папку .git, нашел там файл config, отредактировал его и удалил всё после [format]. Это помогло. Спасибо всем за помощь!

а как закрыть вопрос тут, не могу найти

Закрываются тут только плохие вопросы. А обычно на вопрос дают сработавший ответ и оставляют на будущее. Ну а этот наверное можно удалить.

Судя по ошибке, в вашей глобальной конфигурации Git, вероятно, указано неправильное значение для опции log формата. Это может быть вызвано тем, что вы неправильно настроили формат вывода для команды git log. Ошибка указывает на неправильный формат --pretty.
Для исправления проблемы выполните следующие шаги:

Проверьте глобальную конфигурацию, где могли быть указаны неправильные параметры:
git config --global --get-all format.pretty

Если вы увидите --oneline то ошибка в этом

Удалите неправильную настройку:
git config --global --unset format.pretty




к сожалению не помогло, все также в консоли:
fatal: invalid --pretty format: --oneline

Попытаюсь ещё раз помочь

Проверьте файл конфигурации .gitconfig:

Удалите всю настройку:
git config --global --unset-all format.pretty



Если проблема сохраняется, попробуйте полностью сбросить настройки:
git config --global --remove-section format

